# How do I display a UUID in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, uuid

I would like to display a `unique code` like a `uuid` generated using `mysql` in a `TextView`.

After creating my `database` table and using a trigger to create `uuid`, I was able to successfully generate a `json` object and implement in `android studio using retrofit`. However, I am able to display all `json` data from `mysql` in `TextView` but not the `uuid` code. The `TextView` shows blank.

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Unique Code"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_80" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unique_code"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:text="CXDT2887A"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/bt_copy_code"
                        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:tint="@color/grey_60"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_content_copy" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

User.java

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String uuid;
private String email;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String companyname;
private String postcode;
private String city;
private String state;
private String phonenumber;
private String address;
private String country;
private String status;
private int currency;
private String language;
private int email_verified;
private String photo;



public User(int id, String uuid, String email, String firstname, String lastname, String companyname, String address, String city,
            String state, String postcode, String country, String phonenumber, String status, int currency,
            String language, int email_verified, String photo) {

    this.id = id;
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.companyname = companyname;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.country = country;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    this.status = status;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.language = language;
    this.email_verified = email_verified;
    this.photo = photo;


}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastname;
}
public String getCompanyName() { return companyname; }
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public String getState() { return state; }
public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
}
public String getStatus() { return status; }
public int getCurrency() { return currency; }
public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}
public int getEmail_verified() { return email_verified; }
public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
tv_unique_code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unique_code);
    bt_copy_code = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_copy_code);
    bt_copy_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Tools.copyToClipboard(getApplicationContext(), tv_unique_code.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    tv_unique_code.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getUser().getUuid());

    parent_view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Comment: remember to add code when asking a question related to code

Comment: add the activity code where you are setting the text to textview

Comment: Well, is the UUID in the data? Have you debugged/logged via logcat/used toast messages/done something else to check that the UUID is there? It's just a string, so there should be no problem displaying it. And do you see the TextView before trying to add the UUID to it? I mean the one that says "CXDT2887A" by default if that's the one you are trying to use.

Comment: Code updated with MainActivity.java

Comment: Actually all the other user data appears when i set it except uuid data. Am not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading the object with a string from:

```
String myId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

You can set the textview to the id by:

```
Textview displayId= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_id);
displayId.setText(User.getId());
```

Hope that answered your question, if not please provide more code of the activity :)

Comment: i have already generated the uuid in php and output is in json format. However when i setText to TextView, it shows blank. the uuid does not show.

Comment: Debugg: Are you sure the id is of type String? Have you tested to log the id  in Logcat at the line before you setText?

Comment: I have been asking my self that question quite recently. But uuid is stored as a varchar in mysql and so i assumed its of type String. However i am not soo sure now as all my varchar variables display in String but the uuid does not. I havnt logged the id yet primary because am using a real device to run and test the app

Comment: You can log even ig you are using a real device, it appears in the "logcat" at thr bottom in android studios

Comment: Can you recommend a tutorial on this for me

Comment: Type "android studios logcat" into Youtube and pick the one you like

Comment: Thanks Lukas for the help